# SQL select count for more than one like

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to get it to work if it is a one-count condition. How do I make it work for multiple conditions?

```
SELECT count(TableName.DeviceName where DeviceName like 'AR%' ) as DEVICE_Type_A,
       count(TableName.DeviceName where DeviceName like 'R%' ) as DEVICE_Type_B,
       count(TableName.DeviceName where DeviceName like 'P%' ) as DEVICE_Type_C,
       count(TableName.DeviceName where DeviceName like 'AM%' ) as DEVICE_Type_D,
  FROM DB.TableName TableName
 WHERE TableName.DURATIONMIN > '180'
```

Comment: Well, your question really doesnt specify much about what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use case statements!

```
SELECT count(case when DeviceName like 'AR%' then 1 end) as DEVICE_Type_A,
       count(case when DeviceName like 'R%' then 1 end) as DEVICE_Type_B,
       count(case when DeviceName like 'P%' then 1 end) as DEVICE_Type_C,
       count(case when DeviceName like 'AM%' then 1 end) as DEVICE_Type_D
FROM DB.TableName TableName
WHERE TableName.DURATIONMIN > '180'
```

I left the count in.  Personally, I think "sum" is clearer:

```
SELECT sum(case when DeviceName like 'AR%' then 1 else 0 end) as DEVICE_Type_A,
       sum(case when DeviceName like 'R%' then 1 else 0 end) as DEVICE_Type_B,
       sum(case when DeviceName like 'P%' then 1 else 0 end) as DEVICE_Type_C,
       sum(case when DeviceName like 'AM%' then 1 else 0 end) as DEVICE_Type_D
FROM DB.TableName TableName
WHERE TableName.DURATIONMIN > '180'
```

Comment: Thanks alot man, you are lifesaver, that worked, I have question why did it worked in sum brackets without putting tablename.column) if you can answer don't have to.

Comment: The alias is optional when these is one table.  I just removed it to make the SQL more readable.  In practice, you should include table aliases, so I admit to this being bad practice.  However, it is redundant to make the alias the same as the name.  Instead, use some simple abbreviation such as "tn" that evokes "TableName" while being much shorter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll include it back because I'm working with over 20 DB and over 1000's of Table in total.

Comment: +1   This approach is usually the most efficient. For a really large table, where we are counting a very small number of rows... and with a suitable index (for example, on `(DeviceName,DurationMin)` it might be beneficial (performance-wise) to add a predicate to the `WHERE` clause,  `AND (DeviceName LIKE 'A%' OR DeviceName LIKE 'P%' OR DeviceName like 'R%')`. (Technically, these are called CASE "expressions".)

Answer (score 1):

You should use subselects:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT count(*) form TableName.DeviceName where DeviceName like 'AR%' ) as DEVICE_Type_A,
    (SELECT count(*) from TableName.DeviceName where DeviceName like 'R%' ) as DEVICE_Type_B,
    (SELECT count(*) from TableName.DeviceName where DeviceName like 'P%' ) as DEVICE_Type_C,
    (SELECT count(*) from TableName.DeviceName where DeviceName like 'AM%' ) as DEVICE_Type_D,
FROM DB.TableName TableName
WHERE TableName.DURATIONMIN > '180'
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I get this error "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Table does not exist. ORA-00942: table or view does not exist at "

Comment: I don't know your database schema, in this error you don't have table (for example typo error).

Comment: I will play around with code you helped me with, thanks again.